# Are they the "same"? CodeWars

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, compare

**HERE IS THE FULL QUESTION DESCRIPTION**

Given two arrays a and b write a function comp(a, b) (compSame(a, b) in Clojure) that checks whether the two arrays have the "same" elements, with the same multiplicities. "Same" means, here, that the elements in b are the elements in a squared, regardless of the order.

Examples

**Valid arrays**

```
a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]  
b = [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
```

`comp(a, b)` returns `true` because in `b`:

1. 121 is the square of 11,
2. 14641 is the square of 121,
3. 20736 the square of 144,
4. 361 the square of 19,
5. 25921 the square of 161, and so on.

It gets obvious if we write b's elements in terms of squares:

**Invalid arrays**

```
a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11] 
b = [11*11, 121*121, 144*144, 19*19, 161*161, 19*19, 144*144, 19*19]
```

If we change the first number to something else, `comp` may **not** return `true` anymore:

```
a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]  
b = [132, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
```

`comp(a,b)` returns `false` because in `b`, 132 is not the square of any number of `a`.

```
a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]  
b = [121, 14641, 20736, 36100, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
```

`comp(a,b)` returns `false` because in `b`, 36100 is not the square of any number of a.

**Remarks**

1. `a` or `b` might be `[]` (all languages).
2. `a` or `b` might be `nil` or `null` or `None` (except in Haskell, Elixir, C++, Rust).
3. If `a` or `b` are `nil` (or null or None), the problem doesn't make sense so return `false`.
4. If `a` or `b` are **empty** the result is evident by itself.

**Note for C**

1. The two arrays have the same size (> 0) given as parameter in function comp.

**MY QUESTION:**

> Can you come up with a test case where I do not meet the desired
>   specefications??
>
> I am stuck on 1 basic test not being passed (expected
>   result: true but my code returns false)

**MY CODE ATTEMPT**

```
function isTrue(el){
  return el === true;
}

function comp(array1, array2){
  if(array1.length === 0 || array2.length === 0){
    return false;
  }
  var arr = array1.map(function(num){return num*num});
  var arr2 = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(array2.includes(arr[i])){
      arr2.push(true);
      var a = array2.indexOf(arr[i]);
     array2.splice(a,1);
    } else{
      arr2.push(false);
    }
  }
  return arr2.includes(false) ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: What is the range of the input? I guess you get wired behavior if the input numbers are too large. Consider taking the root of elements in `array2` instead of squaring elements in `array1`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Integer_range_for_Number

Comment: I found the solution, apparently if the two arrays were empty I should have returned true.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest possible way:

```
const comp = (a1, a2) => {
  if (!a1 || !a2 || a1.length !== a2.length) return false;
  return a1.map(x => x * x).sort().toString() === a2.sort().toString();
}
```

Comment: everytime I see a 1 to 3 liner that summarizes my code the length of a story I am amazed.One truly must master the built in objects of a language

Comment: I go tthe answer soon after posting but it was not nearly this clean.

Comment: Just a note, a one liner and/or short code isn't necessarily optimal. I see how many interations are here.. first by `.map` and then the `.sort` twice.